# stable, mainline linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

My question is about understanding `mainline, stable` kernel versions. Let us take the example of a `5.18` mainline. My understanding is that 5.18 is the `mainline` and `5.18.1` is the `stable` kernel. For production companies use `5.18` or `5.18.1`? From the kernel.org site:

> Stable
> After each mainline kernel is released, it is considered "stable." Any bug fixes for a stable kernel are backported from the mainline tree and applied by a designated stable kernel maintainer. There are usually only a few bugfix kernel releases until next mainline kernel becomes available -- unless it is designated a "longterm maintenance kernel." Stable kernel updates are released on as-needed basis, usually once a week.

What does this mean? Does it mean `5.18.1` bugfix release will be backported to `5.18`?

Answer (score 1):

> For production companies use 5.18 or 5.18.1?

The kernels on kernel.org are released or considered to be "stable" only by the kernel developers. Almost no distro or company uses them right away as is, without testing. "Stable" here is not what you think it is. It's a counterpart of RC (release candidates) or Linux-next kernels which are definitely not "stable", i.e. they undergo major changes and may contain serious errors or regressions.

For production-quality kernels you need to refer to distros which actually guarantee some sort of testing and stability, e.g. RHEL and its derivatives.

Usual community backed distros don't have the resources and money to guarantee their kernel releases are production ready.

Comment: +1 since I do agree with your answer. I would have added A/ that for many distributions the "stable" qualifier implies at least no known regression towards previous stable and B/ that taking into account that prominent Red-Hat devs are also major LK contributors I hold LTS versions of production ready grade.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, a mainline kernel is declared `stable`, and is released. This is what your sample block states.

From this point on, only the `mainline` is developed further, and will be the candidate for the NEXT stable kernel.

Any `bugfix` though (a commit fixing exactly one thing https://docs.kernel.org/process/stable-kernel-rules.html) that is introduced to the `mainline` will be transferred to the `stable` branch also. This is called `backporting`.